# Expand variadic template to array of static members

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I've defined a base class template:

```
template<class actual_class>
class base
{
public:
    static const int value;
}
```

and the definition of `value` depends on the `actual_class` tparam.

Next, I have a bunch of derived classes from `base`, let's call them `a` and `b`. Let's also say that `a::value = 5` and `b::value = 10`.

Now, in a method template where I need to access the static values from a parameter pack. I'd like to have them in a vector.

```
template<class... derived_from_bases>
void foo(irrelevant_class<derived_from_bases...> irrelevant)
{
    // std::vector<int> values = { ... }
    ...
}
```

For the function called with < a, b > tparams I'd like the values vector to look like this:

```
std::vector<int> values = {5 /* a::value */, 10 /* b::value */};
```

Also having an std::array instead of an std::vector would be a nice touch.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a vector, you just need

```
std::vector<int> values = { derived_from_bases::value... };
```

If you have C++17, you can get a `std::array` the same way like

```
std::array values = { derived_from_bases::value... };
```

and [CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) will deduce the type and size of the array for you.  If you do not have C++17, then you can use

```
std::array<int, sizeof...(derived_from_bases)> values = { derived_from_bases::value... };
```